# Answer being down-voted as an act of rebellion

Tags: discussion

I believe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34385046/how-to-indent-the-code-so-the-answer-will-be-correct/34385097#34385097) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522154/convert-a-number-i-e-5-to-length-of-an-array/34522184#34522184) answer has been down-voted due to a malicious user. These down-votes are for questions that could not be found by the front page, but would be found if looked at my profile. Can the mods investigate this? I have reason to believe it is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/726802/helper) user.

Edit: A user seems to have reverted their down-votes. Also, the user mentioned above can be seen making senseless edits to my answers in order to be able to down-vote.

1. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34522184/revisions)
2. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34385097/revisions)

Comment: How exactly do you want mods to investigate this - go to the user's house and interrogate them about their motivation for the downvotes (if it was them)?

Comment: I'm just disappointed that a user would perform malicious activities in this community as an act of vengeance.

Comment: 1. Votes are anonym so you can't tell who voted on which post 2. mods can't see single votes for each single user. So they can only see bigger voting patterns. And two, three votes aren't many votes. (@Pekka웃 SO will send a swat team of mods to the user's house :)

Comment: What downvotes?

Comment: Moderators **can not** see individual votes made between users - nor will they ever be able to. That's the key to a free diplomacy and free voting community. They're able to see **voting patterns** though... so I wouldn't stress out too much right now...

Comment: As the downvotes appear to be reversed now, that point is probably moot. regarding the pointless edits to both  your answers, you can revert those and should consider flaging for moderator attention if they happen again. note that votes are locked in after some time unless the post is edited, so those edits may have been done for purpose of reversing the previous downvotes. no reason to let them stand though.

Comment: @HugoRune can you show me how to flag the edit? I believe this is clear proof of abusing the system and I believe that it should be brought to attention to mods.

Comment: Also, I have heard some people before saying "hey can someone do an edit so I can reverse my vote" ... move-on

Comment: you can flag the answer for moderator attention, and enter the details in the text box that appears. however i would not do that unless such an edit happens repeatedly. you can easily revert the current edit yourself, no need to involve the mods for that.

Comment: ["Rebellion"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rebellion) doesn't seem like the word you want. Maybe ["retribution"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/retribution)?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/217863

Comment: @JoshCaswell it could be rebellion against answering awfully researched questions... So could be perfectly valid choice of words. :) "How to indent JavaScript source" (or maybe "teach me to read quiz questions") does not look very well researched - and one could vote down such answers...

Comment: For what it is worth, the User mentioned in my question is now banned.

Answer (score 10):

Moderators can step in if a user is egregiously abusing the system to downvote someone else's contributions.

However, one or two downvotes is *way* below any threshold for such a thing to happen, regardless what the motivation for those downvotes was. It doesn't matter - everyone is free to vote as they please, as long as it's not deemed abusive.

As long as it stays at that level, you'll simply have to live with it. It's happened to most of us, too, at some point.

It is not a nice experience, but in the long run it is no big deal.

If more downvotes continue to trickle in on a daily basis (that has happened when the culprit was clever enough to stay under the radar), flag for moderator attention.